# An easy question on the general properties of reflections

Tags: category-theory

Good morning to everybody. I'm involved in the study of reflective categories (from Borceux' book) and I have a silly doubt.

Recall that if $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is a functor and $B$ is an object in $\mathcal{B}$, a reflection of $B$ along $F$ is a pair $(R_B,\eta_B)$ where $R_B$ is an object of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\eta_B: B \to F(R_B)$ is a morphism of $\mathcal{B}$ such that given an object $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$ and a morphism $b: B \to F(A)$, then there exists a unique $a: R_B \to A$ such that $F(a) \circ \eta_B=b$.

When for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$ the reflection of $B$ along $F$ exists and such a reflection $(R_B,\eta_B)$ has been chosen, there exists a unique functor $R: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$ such that $R(B)=R_B$ for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

In such a setting, if $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is a full embedding, it is well known that $R_A=A$ and $\eta_A=Id_A$ for every object $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$ (that is contained in $\mathcal{B}$).

In the general case, suppose that $B=F(A)$. Is it again true that $R_B=A$ and $\eta_B=Id_B$?

POSSIBLE ANSWER:
My intuition says not, because the counit $\epsilon: R \circ F \implies Id_{\mathcal{A}}$ is only a natural transformation. In the case of the reflective full subcategory, we have that $R \circ F$ is naturally isomorphic to $Id_{\mathcal{A}}$. In the general context, this fails. Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally false. Consider the (non-full) inclusion functor $I\colon\mathsf{Mon}\to\mathsf{sGrp}$ of the category of monoids into the category of semigroups. It has a left adjoint $L\colon\mathsf{sGrp}\to\mathsf{Mon}$ which sends a semigroup $S$ to the monoid $S\sqcup\{e\}$, where $e$ acts as the unit object of the monoid structure, and restricted to $S$ the monoid structure is the semigroup structure we already had on $S$. You are asking if, for a general monoid $M$, it holds that $LM\cong M$, and if the unit of the adjunction satisfies $\eta_M=\mathrm{id}_M$. However, $LM=M\sqcup\{e\}$ and the adjunction unit is the inclusion $M\hookrightarrow M\sqcup\{e\}$, which is indeed a semigroup homomorphism, but generally not an isomorphism, let alone an identity.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent statement to $(R_B, \eta_B)$ being a reflection of $B$ is that the map $\hom(R_B, A) \to \hom(B, F(A))$ given by $a \mapsto F(a) \circ \eta_B$ is an isomorphism. For the case that you're talking about with $B = F(A)$, $R_B = A$ and $\eta_B = \mathrm{id}_{F(A)}$, this is says that $\hom(A, A) \to \hom(F(A), F(A))$ given by $a \mapsto F(a)$ is an isomorphism.

So $(A, \mathrm{id}_{F(A)})$ is a reflection of $F(A)$ precisely if $F$ is fully faithful on morphisms from $A$ to itself. It's not too hard to find examples where this isn't true. For example, most constant functors will fail to be faithful. Lots of structure-forgetting functors won't be full.